# Understanding cdr and car differences in linked lists

Tags: c++, pointers

I am wondering about the differences between `setcdr`, `setcar`, `cdr` and `car`.  I know `car` refers to the value of a node and the `cdr` functions are referring to the next pointers in the node, but I don't understand the differences.

The `setcdr` function:

```
void setcdr( Node* p, Node* q ) {

    assert (p != nullptr);
    p->next = q;
}
```

is `void`, so how is this setting up the linked list?  Shouldn't it return a `Node`?

```
//returns the data field of the Node

// if p is the nullptr, we cannot get its data ...exit abruptly

int car( Node* p ) {

    assert (p != nullptr);
    return( p->value );
}

// returns the next field of the Node

// if p is the nullptr, we cannot get its next.... exit abruptly

Node* cdr( Node* p ) {

    assert (p != nullptr);
    return( p->next );
}

void setcar( Node* p, int x ) {

    assert (p != nullptr);
    p->value = x;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) regarding formatting code blocks properly.  Backticks are only necessary for single-line code.

Answer (score 6):

The terms `car` and `cdr` come from LISP (see the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR)). Their use in this context probably refers to a particular way of constructing a linked list:

1. Every node has two parts, `car` and `cdr`.
2. The `car` piece points to the content of the node, and the `cdr` piece points to the next node in the list.
3. The `cdr` piece of the last node in the list is set to `NULL`, or its equivalent.

Using this approach, the function `setcdr` would *modify* the `cdr` piece of an *existing* node (i.e. set a node's pointer to the next node in the list), so there's nothing to return.

There should be a way to create a new `Node`, but it won't use any of the functions you mentioned in your post.

Comment: can you take a look at my edited question, so what is the function cdr doing? It's that looking at the next node in the linked list?

Comment: @user2963817 Correct. The function `cdr` returns the node following the node passed to it.